# iText Sharp nested table colspan

Tags: c#, itext

I have a main table 'table' with  3 columns of width {50f,25f,25f}.I created 2 nested tables . 
In nested table 1,

```
                PdfPTable nested12 = new PdfPTable(1);


                PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell1 of nested table1", bodyFontnormalItalic));
                cell1.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                nested12.AddCell(cell1);

                PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell2 of nested table1", bodyFontLight));
                cell2.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                nested12.AddCell(cell2);


                PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell3 of nested table1", bodyFontLight));
                cell3.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                nested12.AddCell(cell3);



                PdfPCell nesthousing12 = new PdfPCell(nested12);
                nesthousing12.Padding = 0f;
                nesthousing12.Colspan = 1;
                table.AddCell(nesthousing12);
```

Nested table 2 is :

```
                    PdfPTable nestedTable2 = new PdfPTable(1);

                    PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell1 of nested table 2", bodyFontnormalItalic));
                    cell4.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                    nestedTable2.AddCell(cell4);  //here 2 cells of colspan=1 needed

                    PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell2 of     nested table 2", bodyFontLight));
                    cell5.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                    nestedTable2.AddCell(cell5);


                    PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell3 of nested table 3", bodyFontLight));
                    cell6.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
                    nestedTable2.AddCell(cell6);

                    PdfPCell nesthousing = new PdfPCell(nestedTable2);
                    nesthousing.Padding = 0f;
                    nesthousing.Colspan = 2;
                    table.AddCell(nesthousing);
```

For nested table 2, i used Colspan=2 . I need nestedtable2 in the bellow format. First row of nested table2 should have 2 cells.

[image]

So how can i create like this ? can you please help me.

edit: 
[image]

Above Table is what the exact output i need. so i created one table with 6 columns. inner table of 3 columns for address and other details.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You say you have a main table 'table' with 3 columns of width `{50f,25f,25f}`, but that doesn't correspond with the image you share. Your nested table 2 has two columns in the image, but in your code, nested table 2 only has 1 column. Your question isn't accurate. I'll try to answer it based on the image you shared, but my answer could be wrong because your question is wrong.

Comment: nesthousing.Colspan = 2;  will merge 2 colums. i mensioned it in nested table 2.

Comment: That doesn't any make sense to me, nor should it make sense to you.

Comment: Rowspan is not defined. so i cant merge 2 rows. :(

Comment: If `Rowspan` isn't defined, you're using an obsolete version of iTextSharp. You need to upgrade! Then again: you don't need rowspan. All you need is common sense.

Comment: Just an extra complaint and then I'll update my answer to show you how simple the solution is. If you are using iTextSharp, more specifically: if you are using iTextSharp to create *invoices*, then why don't you go to the [official iText web site](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books) to download a free ebook called [ZUGFeRD: The Future of Invoicing](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ZUGFeRD.html). That book explains from A to Z how to create invoices that look like [this](http://developers.itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/C7F1.png).

Answer (score 3):

I am ignoring the code in your question, because I don't understand it. I only understand the image you shared and I've written some pseudo code that allows you to create a table that looks like this:

[image]

This looks more or less like the desired result, doesn't it? Now it's up to you to convert the following pseudo code to C#.

This is the code to draw the border of the main table:

```
public class BorderEvent implements PdfPTableEvent {
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths, float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart, PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        float width[] = widths[0];
        float x1 = width[0];
        float x2 = width[width.length - 1];
        float y1 = heights[0];
        float y2 = heights[heights.length - 1];
        PdfContentByte cb = canvases[PdfPTable.LINECANVAS];
        cb.rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        cb.stroke();
    }
}
```

This is the code that creates the full table:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
    table.setTableEvent(new BorderEvent());
    table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 12, 8, 1});
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    // first row
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Main table"));
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setColspan(4);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // second row
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("nested table 1");
    table.addCell("nested table 2");
    table.addCell("");
    // third row
    // third row cell 1
    table.addCell("");
    // third row cell 2
    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table1.addCell("cell 1 of nested table 1");
    table1.addCell("cell 2 of nested table 1");
    table1.addCell("cell 2 of nested table 1");
    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(table1));
    // third row cell 3
    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);
    table2.getDefaultCell().setMinimumHeight(10);
    table2.addCell("");
    table2.addCell("");
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 2 of nested table 2"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table2.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("cell 3 of nested table 2"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table2.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(table2));
    // third row cell 4
    table.addCell("");
    // fourth row
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setColspan(4);
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    cell.setMinimumHeight(16);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

As you can see, the nested table 2 needs to have 2 columns so that you can have two cells in its first row. Obviously, you need to define a colspan of 2 for the two cells that are used for row 2 and 3.

You may have noticed that the pseudocode is actually working Java code. It shouldn't be a problem for you to interpret that code and to port it to C#.

### Update

You seem to have a knack for making simple things look complicated. In your original drawing, you drew an extra rectangle around the desired result. In my answer, I mimicked that drawing in the [NestedTables4](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/2058#1643-nestedtables4.java) example and you weren't happy with the result.

Now you've simplified your drawing and I made a [NestedTables5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/2058#1645-nestedtables5.java) example that is much easier to understand. The result looks like this:

[image]

In spite of the simplicity, you still make the problem sound complex. You say (and I quote): *i created one table with 6 columns. inner table of 3 columns.* But that doesn't make sense, does it?

If you want to create this complete structure in 1 single table, using two inner tables, you need a table with 7 colums:

[image]

The first cell has colspan 3 and contains a table with 1 column and 3 rows. The second cell has colspan 4 and contains a table with 2 columns and 3 rows. The third cell in the lower part of the table always has colspan 2.

That's elementary logic. However, why would you make a simple table like this so complex? As documented, `PdfPTable` was designed in such a way that you can add multiple instances of `PdfPTable` one after the other, without even noticing that there are different tables at play.

This is what I did in the [NestedTables5](http://developers.itextpdf.com/node/2058#1645-nestedtables5.java) example. I created a table with 2 columns for the upper part and a table with 6 columns for the lower part:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    // Header part
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{50, 50});
    // first cell
    PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table1.getDefaultCell().setMinimumHeight(30);
    table1.addCell("Address 1");
    table1.addCell("Address 2");
    table1.addCell("Address 3");
    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(table1));
    // second cell
    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(2);
    table2.addCell("Date");
    table2.addCell("Place");
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("References"));
    cell.setMinimumHeight(40);
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table2.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("destination"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table2.addCell(cell);
    table.addCell(new PdfPCell(table2));
    // second row
    cell = new PdfPCell();
    cell.setColspan(2);
    cell.setMinimumHeight(16);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    // Body part
    table = new PdfPTable(6);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{ 1, 2, 6, 1, 2, 2 });
    table.addCell("sl no");
    table.addCell("qty");
    table.addCell("Product");
    table.addCell("units");
    table.addCell("rate");
    table.addCell("total");
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ) {
        table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT);
        table.getDefaultCell().setMinimumHeight(16);
        table.addCell(String.valueOf(++i));
        table.addCell("");
        table.addCell("");
        table.addCell("");
        table.addCell("");
        table.addCell("");
    }
    table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(3);
    table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.LEFT | Rectangle.RIGHT | Rectangle.BOTTOM);
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("");
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

That gives you the result as shown in your second drawing. See [nested_tables5.pdf](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/sandbox/raw/master/cmpfiles/tables/cmp_nested_tables5.pdf) and compare it with what you need.

### Important

It looks as if you're creating invoices with iTextSharp and that you have been trying to do so since March 28 (that's a week ago). In the future, please read the documentation first. That will save you plenty of time that you would otherwise lose in a *trial-and-error* process. You can download an ebook entitled [ZUGFeRD: The Future of Invoicing](http://pages.itextpdf.com/ZUGFeRD.html) for free, and you can even browse that book for free online: [ZUGFeRD: The Future of Invoicing](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/zugferd-future-invoicing). It explains step by step how to create invoices such as the one shown in the figure below:

[image]

Why would you reinvent the wheel if all the examples are out there?

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Sr No")) { Rowspan = 2, BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY });
PdfPCell CellZero1 = table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Name")) { Rowspan = 2, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY });
CellZero1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
table.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Phone")) { Rowspan = 2, BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY });
PdfPTable nestedTable = new PdfPTable(2);


PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("12") );
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("545445444"));

nestedTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("First Name")){ BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY });
nestedTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Last Name")) { BackgroundColor = BaseColor.GRAY });



for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
{
    nestedTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("data" + i)) );
    nestedTable.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("last" + i)) );

}

cell2.AddElement(nestedTable);

table.AddCell(cell1);
table.AddCell(cell2);
table.AddCell(cell3);


doc.Add(table);
```

Comment: How exactly does your code relate to the question? Ok, your code appears to deal with tables, in particular nested tables, but the question is about achieving a very specific layout using nested tables and your code does not create that layout at all.